# Async.js jump out of series

Tags: node.js, async.js

I am using Caolan's brilliant [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). I am executing a series of functions. In the first function, I have a condition that should skip all the rest of the series' functions and directly go to the final callback:

```
async.series([
    function one (next) {
        if(!condition) {
            // skip all the other functions and go to final callback
        }
        // do stuff
        return next();
    },
    function two (next) {
        // do stuff
        return next();
    },
    function three (next) {
        // do stuff
        return next();
    }
], function (err) {
    // final callback stuff
});
```

So if in function one condition isn't met, directly go to the final callback.

The [Async series docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) state

> If any functions in the series pass an error to its callback, no more functions are run, and callback is immediately called with the value of the error.

But throwing an error does not look like a clean approach to me. To be able to handle "real" errors correctly in the final callback, I would have to introduce a fake error... Is there any other, clean way?

Answer (score 1):

Following up on how I solved this for now. I do throw a specific error to skip the rest of the series, excluding this specific error from general error handling in the final callback:

```
    async.series([
        function one (next) {
            if(!condition) {
                return next('condition_not_met');
            }
            return next();
        },
        function two (next) {
            // this isn't executed if condition isn't met in function one
            return next();
        }
    ], function (err) {
        if (err && err !== 'condition_not_met') {
            // general error handling
        }
        // do more stuff
    });
```

I'd still be interested if this is the way async.series is intended to be used - or if there is a more elegant way of handling my scenario. Cheers.